# Does anyone know if it is possible to do getProgramAccounts inside a solana onchain program?

Tags: solana-program

I know this exists for the Rust client: https://solanacookbook.com/guides/get-program-accounts.html#facts

But not sure if it works inside a solana onchain program? Has anyone tested this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This cannot be done.  The address of all accounts a transaction intends to interact with must be declared up front, otherwise the runtime can't resolve write conflicts during scheduling.  On demand accounts loading, as requested here, is antithetical to Solana's design

Answer (score 2):

Hello :) What problem are you trying to solve? I'm confused because you're linking to a RPC node call which is very useful to discover a certain type of program account for a program but this only works outside of a solana program.

You're probably already aware of this but when calling a solana program instruction all the data accounts you wish to read or modify data from needs to be passed into the context (the request input params). So it's not possible to read data from an arbitrary number of accounts that will first be known while executing the such as getProgramAccounts. I think at current time you can maximum pass in 30 data accounts when calling a solana program instruction.

Comment: clarifying questions ought to be asked as comment's to the OP

Answer (score 1):

`getProgramAccounts` is an RPC call that returns a filtered list of accounts owned by a given program. There is no corresponding method available in the solana rust client that can be called onchain.

Furthermore, as mentioned by others, if you do need to access account data inside a program the solana runtime requires you to provide all those account public keys inside serialized the transaction.